# MariaDB database COLLATE change query

Tags: database, character-encoding, mariadb, collation

I have 3 queries to change the COLLATION. They should work but they does not. Looks like only [!varchar] columns by 2nd query are affected. Can anybody tell what is the problem there? I need to convert from **utf8_general_ci** to **utf8_bin**.
I get results like:

```
ALTER TABLE AO_21F425_MESSAGE_MAPPING_AO MODIFY MESSAGE_ID varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE AO_21F425_MESSAGE_MAPPING_AO MODIFY USER_HASH varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE AO_38321B_CUSTOM_CONTENT_LINK MODIFY LINK_URL varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

and so on... but no changes in DB.

1) Change columns with type VARCHAR

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name,
        '` MODIFY `', column_name, '` ', DATA_TYPE, '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
        ') CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin',
        (CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END), ';')
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
AND
(
    CHARACTER_SET_NAME != 'utf8'
    OR
    COLLATION_NAME != 'utf8_bin'
);
```

---

2) Change columns with other than VARCHAR type

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name,
    '` MODIFY `', column_name, '` ', DATA_TYPE,
    ' CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin',
    (CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END), ';')
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name'
AND DATA_TYPE != 'varchar'
AND
(
    CHARACTER_SET_NAME != 'utf8'
    OR
    COLLATION_NAME != 'utf8_bin'
);
```

---

3) Change table level

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',  table_name, ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;')
FROM information_schema.TABLES AS T, information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS C
WHERE C.collation_name = T.table_collation
AND T.table_schema = 'my_database_name'
AND
(
    C.CHARACTER_SET_NAME != 'utf8'
    OR
    C.COLLATION_NAME != 'utf8_bin'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. It does its thing very well. Just paste in console.

```
DB="your_database_name"; ( echo 'ALTER DATABASE `'"$DB"'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;'; mysql "$DB" -e "SHOW TABLES" --batch --skip-column-names | xargs -I{} echo 'ALTER TABLE `'{}'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;' ) | mysql "$DB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware; the `ALTER` may not be what you want!

Are you coming from `charset latin1` and the data is correctly encoded as `latin1` now?  Then you need `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...`

Are you coming from `latin1`, but the bytes were utf8?  Then you need *two* alters.

What is your exact situation?

After determining what you really need, please provide the resulting `ALTERs` for us to critique.

These links may help:

- Diagnosis, Best practice, Common problems: [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)
- Fixes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

**more**

In

```
ALTER  TABLE AO_21F425_MESSAGE_MAPPING_AO MODIFY MESSAGE_ID
      varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
```

you must specify the size of the `varchar`.

Comment: Tnx. I edited the question. From UTF8_GENERAL_CI to UTF8_BIN conversion required in my case.

Comment: So, you want to change the `COLLATION` of columns that are _already_ `CHARSET utf8`.  Let's see the generated `ALTERs`.

Comment: Not sure i got You, but this is some of query results:
ALTER TABLE `AO_21F425_MESSAGE_MAPPING_AO` MODIFY `MESSAGE_ID` varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `AO_21F425_MESSAGE_MAPPING_AO` MODIFY `USER_HASH` varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `AO_38321B_CUSTOM_CONTENT_LINK` MODIFY `LINK_URL` varchar CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
and so on.

Comment: @Dzintars - I added some more.

Comment: Tnx. I am not a SQL guy, i can do just simple SQL queries. Can i ask you to copy-paste/edit the query to show me how to set varchar size automatically?
What i need to achieve - i have database with data in it. There is 200+ tables so i don't want to do it manually. I want to have query which will make that conversion at once. I need to have utf8_bin COLLATE at all levels - db, tables and columns.

Comment: @Dzintars - Try using `COLUMN_TYPE` instead of `DATA_TYPE`; that should give you `varchar(123)` instead of simply `varchar`.